# Cross-compiling Boost for ARM

Tags: arm, c++, boost

I'd like to cross-compile Boost for ARM. [Here](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/tasks/crosscompile.html) is some documentation.

Where can I find the file user-config.jam? I don't see it anywhere. Is it something I have to create in the boost root directory?

Comment: It looks like you make it: http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/overview/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says, this file must be in one of these paths (on Linux) : `$HOME or $BOOST_BUILD_PATH`. If not, you seem to have to create it.

If it doesn't find `user-config.jam`, `site-config.jam` is used.

> You can use the --debug-configuration option to find which
>   configuration files are actually loaded.

Answer (score -1):

Inside the boost source code folder, just run the command:

```
find . -name user-config.jam
```

It seems to be

```
./tools/build/v2/user-config.jam
```